do not serialize empty collections (and handle accordingly in deserialization)
I have a bunch of POCOs that can be (de-)serialized from/to json. A lot of content is collections. I want the serialized JSON to only contain a specific property if its collection is not empty (reasons: saving space, making it much easier for humans to see what's relevant). Deserialization of those non-existing properties should result in empty collections in the data.
How do I do that?

JsonIgnoreCondition does not have any entry that does this. It only handles null/default values.

Example POCO:
public class Data
{
    public DocData MainDoc { get; }
    public IList<DocData> SubDocs { get; }

    public Data(DocData mainDoc, IList<DocData> subDocs)
    {
        MainDoc = mainDoc;
        SubDocs = subDocs;
    }
}

I do the (de-)serialization with JsonSerializer.Serialize and JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data> with JsonSerializerOptions argument new JsonSerializerOptions { DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull }.
Actual JSON if there is no content inside SubDocs:
{
    "MainDoc": { ... },
    "SubDocs": [ ]
}

Wanted JSON if there is no content inside SubDocs:
{
    "MainDoc": { ... }
}


I already tried writing an own converter returning null if the collection is empty:
public class Data
{
    public DocData MainDoc { get; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CollectionConverter))]
    public IList<DocData> SubDocs { get; }
}

internal class CollectionConverter : JsonConverter<IList<DocData>>
{
    public override IList<DocData>? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var deserialized = (IList<DocData>?)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, options);
        return deserialized ?? List<DocData>.Empty;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IList<DocData> values, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (!values.Any())
        {
            writer.WriteNullValue();
            return;
        }

        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var value in values)
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}

, hoping that JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull or JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault would combine well with that. But no, I just get this JSON then:
{
    "MainDoc": { ... },
    "SubDocs": null
}


If you don't want a null value to be printed, why call writer.WriteNullvalue()? What happens if you remoe that one?

Then I get an invalid json output like this: { "MainDoc": { ... }, "SubDocs": }. That's the issue; I cannot tell the deserializer that it should not deserialize the SubDocs at all (if there is no content). At least not in this way. But I don't want to go one step up and manually (de-)serialize the whole Data object just to be able to check for SubDocs' emptyness and react accordingly... because then I would need to write really a lot of code that I want the standard (de-)serialization to just handle on its own.

Have you tried a TypeInfoResolver Modifier as shown in this related question?

You have that in your question but you tried explicitly adding [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)] to your SubDocs Property in Data?

Agree with @SybrenS that a JsonTypeInfo modifier is the way to go because converters don't have the ability to prevent serialization.  So, does C# .Net Core 3.1 System.Text.Json Ignore empty collection in serialization answer your question sufficiently?

Incidentally your public IList<DocData> SubDocs { get; } property seems broken because it is read-only (no setter) but lacks a default allocation such as public IList<DocData> SubDocs { get; } = new List<DocData>();  Thus it's always going to be null.  Does your real type's property have a setter?  Do you need System.Text.Json to construct the property value for you when it is missing or null, or is it already constructed in your real code?

@Ralf Just tried it, does not change a thing. "SubDocs": null still ends up in the JSON.

@dbc Added constructor to Data. Thought it was not relevant for the question so I omitted it initially, but since you're asking if SubDocs is broken, I guess it's better to have it there. So no, SubDocs is not broken, it gets created by Deserialization via the (single) constructor.

OK, for serialization the answer from C# .Net Core 3.1 System.Text.Json Ignore empty collection in serialization almost does what you need, it needs a couple tweaks to handle the fact that you declared your properties as IList<T> rather than List<T>.  For deserialization, System.Text.Json passes null for the missing value, so you could do SubDocs = subDocs ?? new List<DocData>();.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/VqcShK.  Does that answer your question?  Or is modifying the constructor objectionable?

@dbc Modifying the constructor to accommodate System.Text.Json stuff is nothing I want to do.

Then please indicate what you are willing to do.  Seems like you are willing to add attributes like [JsonConverter], anything else?  System.Text.Json's JsonTypeInfo does not provide access to constructor metadata so your precise requirement of intercepting and allocating null constructor parameters is hard to accommodate.

@dbc If there is no other way, I can live with modifying the constructor. But yes, what I'd like to do is intercept the default deserialization process at the point where the constructor is called - so instead of calling the constructor with the arguments gotten from the json there should be some step in-between that can modify these arguments (turn null into empty collection) before calling the constructor.
